# How to convert of D3.js code to react code

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, treemap

I want to use the d3 treemap layout in react .I have imported D3 in my react app . But I cannot use the d3 functions as it is .
Find the code in this link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-thunder-l024x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covert the D3 version to version 3.* and this code will render!

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-waterfall-mpwr1?fontsize=14

Comment: that's great !! do you know how to use this as a breadcrumb driven visualization . When you click on the breadcrumb it goes only one level up even if we want to go to the root node .

Comment: Currently, in the D3 v3 version of the treemap, the 'breadcrumb' does navigate 'up' or 'back' 1 level when clicked.